# Site won't vaidate due to duplicate "class" specifications and issue with radio button label

Tags: validation

I was under the impression that you could specify more than one class attribute on an element. I have done it elsewhere on the site without receiving any validation errors, but for some reason on this one page (appleiphonebuyers.com/quote.html) I get 3 of these errors:

Line 57, Column 41: duplicate specification of attribute "CLASS"

```
<div class="condition-good" class="clearfix">
```

You have specified an attribute more than once. Example: Using the "height" attribute twice on the same "img" tag.

I also have a validation error in my form, where there are radio buttons (appleiphonebuyers.com/sell.html). Is there another way I should apply a label to the group of radio buttons besides using "label for"?

Line 155, Column 44: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

```
… <label for="condition" class="inline"><span class="formstar">*</span> Conditi…
```

Answer (score 2):

One attribute with values separated by space.

```
<div class="condition-good clearfix">
```

For < label for="condition" >, you need an input/select (a form subelement) with an attribute name "condition"

```
<input type="text" name="condition">
```

Usually, people write it like that :

```
<input type="text" name="condition" id="condition">
```

Comment: I've been moving and finally got internet access. Your first suggestion worked, thank you! But regarding the form issue, there already is an input type specified which is "radio". If I add input type="text" then I'll get a text field there which I don't want.